# opacity over gradient background

Tags: css, gradient, opacity

I want to use `opacity` only for this gradient, not for text color. Here is code :

```
.large-thumb {      
position: absolute;    
bottom: 15px;    
z-index: 99;    
padding: 5px 5px 20px;    
color: #fff;    
background: #323232; /* Old browsers */    
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #323232 0%, #858585 50%, #E7E7E7 100%) ; /* FF3.6+ */    
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#323232), color-stop(50%,#858585), color-stop(100%,#E7E7E7)) ; /* Chrome,Safari4+ */    
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #323232 0%,#858585 50%,#E7E7E7 100%) ; /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */    
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #323232 0%,#858585 50%,#E7E7E7 100%) ; /* Opera 11.10+ */    
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #323232 0%,#858585 50%,#E7E7E7 100%) ; /* IE10+ */    
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #323232 0%,#858585 50%,#E7E7E7 100%); /* W3C */    
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#323232',   endColorstr='#E7E7E7',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */      
 width: 291px;    
background:transperent;    
margin-left: 20px;    
 margin-left: 20px;    
    padding-bottom: 20px;    
bottom: 31px;    
-moz-border-radius:25px;     
-webkit-border-radius:25px;     
border-radius:25px;    
}
```

For demo follow link [demo blog](http://infinitytechs.blogspot.in/)

Answer (score 0):

basically yout text color is what it is becouse at `.large-thumb span.xpose_meta`you set it at `#00000` insteed of `#000000`(6 numbers) or `#000` (3 numbers).

There's no opacity around on your project.

And, if possible, next time try to extract the part of the code that it's wrong (html and css) and give it to us in your question, even better if on a jsfiddle (nice info if you don't know jsfiddle **[here](http://irisclasson.com/2013/10/14/what-is-jsfiddle-the-ultimate-guide-for-the-ultimate-lightweight-tool-q-249-250/)**)

Don't expect people solving your problems like: "here is my web, this is not working, fix it for me... ah, don't even expect a single please or even ty in my question"

(and yes, I'm so stupid that still I try to help)

Comment: Thank you for help, I really appreciate. And really sorry for way of my questioning. I wasn't know the proper way those days. Thanks again :)